# What LabelId for date?

Tags: gmail-api

What is the syntax for specifying that you want messages sent after a given date in the users.messages.list api call? For that matter, where is there a list of all the valid LabelId parameters for this api?

Comment: welcome to stack please read [ask]  did you try is there an error in your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would like tthe search query you need to introduce in order to find messages sent after a given date. If so, you can find the specific query in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering). You can also list all the Label Ids for a specific user using the following [method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list).